# How to write gSOAP server using VC++ (VS2008)?

Tags: php, visual-c++, gsoap

I have downloaded gSOAP2.8 from sourceforge. I want to use it for writting a gsoap based server. I need to be able to invoke my C++ code from PHP UI.

My php page would show something like:

```
$res = a + b = ? [Submit]
```

When submit button is clicked I want these parameters to be passed to my c++ function lets say `compute_sum()` ... and this function should be invoked with these parameters, and the results given back to my php page.

I want to write this gsoap based c++ server. Can someone please help me with getting started with it?

I need to know:

1. What kind of c++ code it should it be? (Windows console app, or a windows service)
2. How do I launch this server? (Would it need to be a webservice, hosted over something like apache?)

Answer (score 0):

You can download examples here.
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

I recommend using just console application for a moment. To talk to service you can use phpSoap extension or [Zend_Soap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html).